# IOResources class

Tags: macos, audio, kernel, device-driver, iokit

All virtual device drivers who don't control any hardware devices seem to match on `IOResources` as the `IOProviderClass`.
 Apple says that drivers that match on `IOResources` gets attached to the root of the IORegistry to get system-wide services like BSD kernel and etc...available to the driver.
 What I dont understand is how does your driver gets called by the system since the system doesn't know what device you are controlling? For example how can a virtual audio driver get access to the system audio mix and hardware sample buffer without even attaching to it? 
Since I couldn't find any information on the `IOResources` class I'm asking here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer to your question boils down to the inherent contradiction in what you're asking:

> All virtual device drivers who don't control any hardware devices seem to match on IOResources

vs.

> What I dont understand is how does your driver gets called by the system since the system doesn't know what device you are controlling?

Either there's a real device to control, or there isn't, when it's a virtual device driver. In the case of a real driver, the provider will be a nub or device object, such as IOPCIDevice, IOUSBDevice/IOUSBHostDevice, IOUSBInterface/IOUSBHostInterface, and so on. **The provider of your driver is the device your driver is controlling.**

At the other end, each driver advertises what services it provides to the operating system, other kexts, or to userspace processes. This is signaled mainly by the (super)class type of your driver's main object or any nub objects it creates and registers with the I/O Registry. **Clients which understand these interfaces will in turn match the driver's objects as their providers.**

Your example of audio drivers actually demonstrates 2 ways this can work. OS X's audio subsystem mostly runs in user space - specifically `coreaudiod`. Since OS X 10.8, that includes audio device drivers themselves too, although the deprecated IOAudioDevice/IOAudioEngine kernel API still exists and Apple ships drivers which use it as of OS X 10.11.

In a legacy/kernel audio driver, your driver will implement subclasses of `IOAudioDevice` and `IOAudioEngine` and possibly some other classes. When instances of these classes are registered in the I/O registry, the Core Audio Daemon detects this via the service matching mechanism, and creates user clients for communicating with those kernel objects. Core Audio will match any objects which conform to the `IOAudioEngine` interface - I think this is the question you're asking.

In a modern audio driver, the Audio Server HAL plugin bundle's Info.plist contains the I/O kit matching dictionary. It might directly match a system-provided provider class, such as an IOUSBInterface, if the device can be driven directly. For a PCI device, you'll likely need a custom kext to do the memory-mapping and interrupt handling. This kext will most likely simply subclass IOService, nothing more specific than that, and provide its own user client class. The HAL plugin will then match on that kext's specific driver class name, and open a connection to it with the custom user client class.

I hope that answers your question?

Comment: Hi, I need to write an audio server HAL plugin to do some audio processing before releasing it do the USB device. You've mentioned that the plugin can match IOUSBInterface directly, however so far I've only managed to create new virtual audio devices in the plugin, while I want to control an existing one. I see that system attaches AppleUSBAudio driver to my device, but I can't find a way to control it in my plugin. The only solution that I've found is to somehow block AppleUSBAudio from attaching and do all the USB work myself. I wonder if there is another, possibly easier way to do this.

Comment: @prazuber I'm not sure a HAL plugin is the way to go for that. Audio processing is usually done in [Audio Units](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Your other option is to implement a USB Audio Plugin Kext, [see this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SampleUSBAudioPlugin/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003471). In any case, this is off-topic for this question, so please open a new question. Use the "device-driver"+osx tags so I will see it.

Comment: Audio Unit is not an option because I need to process all audio that is routed to the device, unconditionally. USB Audio Plugin Kext is nice, but I cannot do the processing in the kernel because of library dependencies. Anyway, thank you for your reply, I was hoping that there is a way to somehow do this via HAL plugin on its own, but now I see that the only option is HAL plugin + my own USB driver which I would use from the plugin. Eh, would really love to avoid writing USB stuff ...

Comment: @prazuber [Apple's documentation on USB audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2274/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010116-CH1-TNTAG9) suggests you can change the HAL plugin for the existing USB audio driver. They don't seem to go into detail on how to do that, so you could ask DTS. Reimplementing the USB audio kext seems overkill in any case - at the very least, it should be possible to do this by implementing *both* kernel USB audio and user space coreaudiod plugins.